# Does the iphone podcasts app sync my subscriptions with my itunes subscriptions?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, podcasts, podcasts.app

I just downloaded ios6 and the latest version of podcasts app.  when i look at all of my podcasts, subscriptions is turned off.

Is there anyway to keep my subscriptions in sync between itunes on my computer and iphone podcasts app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the *subscriptions* are synced, just the files. I imagine the reason for this is that if subscriptions synced, your Mac and iOS device would both download all new episodes, rather than having one copy that gets synced between them.